# How to change tkinter label background image on button click

Tags: python, tkinter

```
img= (Image.open("image/frame.png")).resize((240, 240), Image.ANTIALIAS)
new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

panel = tk.Label(right_workspace, image=new_image)
panel.pack(side = "top", fill = "none", expand = "none", pady=29)
```

Thats my label with its image background. Now how can I change this background by a function so everytime my program generates a new qrcode from an input it replaces previous background?

Comment: You can change the options of an existing widget, such as `image`, via its `config()` method. See [Universal widget Methods](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html).

Answer (score 0):

I gather what you're doing, but please leave a minimum reproducible code in future.

Here's an example of how you'd create a functioning tkinter GUI that displays a random image from a list of QR .pngs in a set folder when the button is pressed. You should be able to adapt this to the other part of your program that generates the QR code for you.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
import random


class QrGenerator:
    def __init__(self, main):
        self.main = main
        self.panel = tk.Label(main)
        self.panel.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.button = tk.Button(main, text='Random QR', command=self.random_qr)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def random_qr(self):
        fp = r'C:\Filepath\QR Codes Folder'
        os.chdir(fp)
        qr_code = random.choice(os.listdir(fp))
        print(qr_code)
        img = Image.open(qr_code).resize((240, 240), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self.panel.configure(image=new_image)
        self.panel.image = new_image


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    gui = QrGenerator(root)
    root.mainloop()
```